# Bootstrap capacitor calculation - Which formula should I pick?

Tags: mosfet, gate-driving

In order to calculate capacitance of bootstrap capacitor, I searched around and found two different formula from Ti and Infineon. The [Ti version](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua887/slua887.pdf) states:
[image: Ti Application note]

while [Infineon version](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-HV_Floating_MOS_Gate_Drivers-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559f7cf21200) say:
[image: Infineon Application note]

I think the basic idea behind these two formulas are same: dividing maximum charge may loss when high side MOS conducting, by minimum change of voltage. But I failed to figure it out on myself that why \$Q_g\$ was multiplied by \$2\$ in Infineon's version and again the whole numerator was doubled.

So far the Ti version makes more sense for me as \$Q_g\$ itself is the charge we loss in a switching cycle and also [OnSemi seems to give similar formula (pg 5)](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9674-D.PDF). But I believe there is some reason why Infineon engineers write this formula. I am currently studying how to design half bridge driver and I have selected IR2103 from Infineon. And that's why I want to ask which formula should be used and why?

Comment: I just thought it was a fudge factor.

Comment: the germans have te ability to complicate even very simple things.